# iptables block IP for x hours not working?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, ip-blocking

On my Linux server, I want to ban IPs that access certain ports for 24 hours using IPtables. For this, I use the following IPtables rules:

```
# Check if IP is on banlist, if yes then drop
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -j bancheck
-A bancheck -m recent --name blacklist   --rcheck --reap   --seconds 86400     -j LOG --log-prefix "IPT blacklist_ban: "
-A bancheck -m recent --name blacklist   --rcheck --reap   --seconds 86400     -j DROP

# PUT IPs on banlist
-A banlist -m recent --set --name blacklist -j LOG --log-prefix "IPT add_IP_to_blacklist: "
-A banlist -j DROP

# Ban access to these ports
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 23,25,445,1433,2323,3389,4899,5900   -j LOG --log-prefix "IPT syn_naughty_ports: "
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 23,25,445,1433,2323,3389,4899,5900   -j banlist
```

In the logs, I can verify that this works:

```
Mar 13 02:12:23 kernel: [39534099.648488] IPT syn_naughty_ports: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=... SRC=218.189.140.2 DST=... LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=29768 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=65315 DPT=25 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Mar 13 02:12:23 kernel: [39534099.648519] IPT add_IP_to_blacklist: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=... SRC=218.189.140.2 DST=...4 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=29768 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=65315 DPT=25 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Mar 13 02:12:26 kernel: [39534102.664136] IPT blacklist_ban: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=... SRC=218.189.140.2 DST=... LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=4724 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=65315 DPT=25 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

But then the logs also show that just over 2 hours later, the same IP again accesses my system. Rather than being blocked right at the beginning through the chain "bancheck", the IP can access the port, which results in it being put on the "banlist" again (destination port in both cases was the same port 25).

```
Mar 13 04:35:59 kernel: [39542718.875859] IPT syn_naughty_ports: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=... SRC=218.189.140.2 DST=... LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=4533 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57719 DPT=25 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Mar 13 04:35:59 kernel: [39542718.875890] IPT add_IP_to_blacklist: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=... SRC=218.189.140.2 DST=... LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=4533 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57719 DPT=25 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Mar 13 04:36:02 kernel: [39542721.880524] IPT blacklist_ban: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=... DST=... LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=12505 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57719 DPT=25 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Mar 13 04:36:08 kernel: [39542727.882973] IPT blacklist_ban: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=... SRC=218.189.140.2 DST=... LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=113 ID=29092 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=57719 DPT=25 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

But if I understand the IPtables rules right, it should be blocked within the first few lines, as long as it is within the 24 hours, and not be able to get down that far in the IPtables rule set where it is again being found to violate the ports rule, and again put on the "banlist".

Am I doing something wrong, or do I misunderstand the way the rules work?

Comment: Did you try to test if the rules are actually working? Like try blocking yourself  (of couse trying to access your server from a remote server or location). See while the block is active you can still access the server

Comment: Yes I did and it does work, I am being blocked and my IP shows in the logs just as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Working example for ssh from my server

```
iptables -X black
iptables -N black
iptables -A black -m recent --set --name blacklist -j DROP

iptables -X ssh
iptables -N ssh
iptables -I ssh 1 -m recent --update --name blacklist --reap --seconds 86400 -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p TCP --dport ssh -m state --state NEW -j ssh
```

Don't forget to create the iptables chains with iptables -N

Compare this with your config and see if there are any notable differences.

A more elegant solution would be to use ipset combined with iptables:

timeout
All set types supports the optional timeout parameter when creating a set and adding entries. The value of the timeout parameter for the create command means the default timeout value (in seconds) for new entries. If a set is created with timeout support, then the same timeout option can be used to specify non-default timeout values when adding entries. Zero timeout value means the entry is added permanent to the set. The timeout value of already added elements can be changed by readding the element using the -exist option. 
Example:

```
ipset create test hash:ip timeout 300 
ipset add test 192.168.0.1 timeout 60 
ipset -exist add test 192.168.0.1 timeout 600
```

Comment: Thanks will try this out.

Comment: Your post does not show where and how an IP is ever sent to the chain "black". Do I understand correctly that any IP seeking to access port SSH is send to the chain "ssh", where it is being banned? No further criteria for banning are evident? So, any IP seeking to access your port SSH will be banned for 24 hours?